# Why is the API responding with response code 400?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

Im trying to make an application that sends text and speaker ID to an API, that converts the text to speech and sends it back.

My issue is that the API responds with code 400. URL is correct. Request method is correct.

(You can take a look at the API and find more info [here](https://neurokone.ee/api))

I'll also include my code down below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import java.io.IOException;

class Variables {
    String tekst;
    int speakerID = 7;

}

public class Neurokone {

    public void ConnectToAPIAndSendRequest() throws IOException {
        Variables v = new Variables();

        //Establishes a connection w/ the API.
        URL url = new URL("https://neurokone.cloud.ut.ee/api/v1.0/synthesize");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json; utf-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "audio/wav");

        //This is self explanatory.
        JSONObject jb = new JSONObject();
            jb.put("text:", v.tekst);
            jb.put("speaker_id:", v.speakerID);

            //Sends the request.
            try(OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream()) {
                byte[] input = jb.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                os.write(input, 0, input.length);
            }


            try {
                //Generate a name for the response file based on user input
                String fileName = v.speakerID + "--" + v.tekst.substring(0,10);
                //Download response file
                ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(con.getInputStream());
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                FileChannel fc = fos.getChannel();

                fc.transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                System.out.println("Sinu koodis on viga: " + e);
            }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Variables variables = new Variables();
        Scanner skanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Here i am asking user to choose speaker voice and insert text to be sent to the API.
        System.out.print("Sisesta häälekood (7 - 10): ");
        variables.speakerID = skanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Sisesta sünteesitav tekst: ");
        variables.tekst = skanner.nextLine();
        variables.tekst = skanner.nextLine();
        skanner.close();

        new Neurokone().ConnectToAPIAndSendRequest();

    }


}
```

Im still learning so any other tips are also very welcome

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should include the full error details, if you want help with this, e.g., a stacktrace. Code 400 generally means you are sending a malformed request. Which part exactly is malformed is likely hinted at in the error.

Comment: oh, my bad.

`Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://neurokone.cloud.ut.ee/api/v1.0/synthesize
 at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1927)
 at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1523)
 at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
 at Neurokone.ConnectToAPIAndSendRequest(Neurokone.java:48)
 at Neurokone.main(Neurokone.java:70)`

Answer (score 2):

you have two problems:

```
  jb.put("text:", v.tekst);
  jb.put("speaker_id:", v.speakerID);
```

`text:` -> `text` and `speaker_id:` -> `speaker_id` without `:`

The second problem is with the documentation
`speaker_id` -> `speakerId`, but if you leave it blank it defaults to 7

here is my curl request:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://neurokone.cloud.ut.ee/api/v1.0/synthesize \
  -d '{ "text": "Hello", "speakerId": "4"}'
```